# Stovetop espresso maker/ steamer — instructions

Tags: espresso, steamed-milk

I’ve got a stovetop espresso maker/steamer that I picked up from my parents’ house. Can anyone point me to instructions on how to best use it? I know someone on here has got one, as I’ve seen a question posted about it…[image: coffee maker on hob]

Comment: Readers, please see the other post about such a device: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/4853/1118

Comment: Maybe I'll take some photos next time I make a coffee and post them here as an answer.

Comment: @steveluscher I understand the principles of a moka pot, but I don't understand what the vertical/horizontal business is. I tried using as a moka put with the lever vertical but the coffee wasn't hot (but then how could it have been forced through the wand if it wasn't hot??? physics is not my strong point, fyi). And then I don't know how to let steam build up for frothing milk. Am most confused.

Answer (score 1):

Join me as I make a latte.

First, fill the boiler just under the pressure release valve, prepare a basket of coffee grounds (I prepared 16g worth), and insert the filter and seal into the lid.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker filled with boiling water, with a basket of coffee grounds beside it]

Drop the basket in.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker with a basket of coffee]

Screw the lid on tight and move the valve into the open position.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker with the valve open]

Immediately put it on the stove. I put it on high for 50 seconds then turn the stove off to let it coast until there's a shot or two of coffee in the pitcher.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker on a stove, with a pitcher ready to catch the brewed coffee]

If the coffee hasn't started to run by the time you turn the stove off, just wait. If it still hasn't started to run, adjust the time you leave it on high.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker brewing some coffee into a pitcher]

I run some cold water over the boiler until it's cool enough to open.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker being run under cold water]

Clean the boiler and fill it back up with boiling water. This time, just the filter and seal – no basket.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker filled with boiling water]

Screw the lid on tight, this time with the valve in the closed position.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker with the valve in the closed position]

Put it back on the stove, on high. When the boiler is up to pressure (the bottom of mine starts to get just round enough that you can rock it back and forth) submerge the nozzle in a pitcher of milk and open the valve. Milk steaming technique is outside of the scope of this tour.

[image: A stovetop coffee maker steaming some milk]

Close the valve before pulling the pitcher of milk away. Now there's nothing left to do but improve your bad latte art.

[image: Bad latte art]

Comment: Thank you, thank you!

Comment: No need to thank me, @Julia; just upvote and click the checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

While I've never seen that kind of gadget before, I assume it's essentially a moka pot. If so, there should be a basket in the bottom of the gadget and a chamber for water beneath it. The idea is that you heat water to produce steam until the steam builds enough pressure to push through the coffee. The roof of this bottom chamber then condenses into a funnel near the center. The continuing pressure provided by the generated steam will push steam and extracted coffee solids up the funnel until it reaches the top chamber, condenses, and collects there. That's coffee.

This device seems to feature a novel valve which I assume is capable of redirecting the steam. Honestly this strikes me as a terrible idea because normal moka pots don't generate sufficient pressure to power a steam wand. Also this device looks... dangerous. You'd have to hold it to turn the valve, and there doesn't appear to be a heat safe handle or grip to support that. Better use some hefty oven mitts because that sucker will get hot.

Also that device won't actually make espresso. Moka pot coffee is quite different from espresso. You may well like it once you get the hang of it, but to me a moka pot is sort of like an in-the-middle between a French press and a pour-over. Which is to say, it's not espresso. They do make good coffee though as long as you don't burn it.

Comment: I think this is just a steam wand. It's filled with water and the steam can only escape through the nozzle. I don't think it's meant for making coffee; it's for steaming milk.

Comment: OP says it is an espresso maker / milk fritter, and the black piece on top looks like a valve handle. Hard to say for sure without seeing the inside.

Comment: The text on the photo [here](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/4853/1118) implies that the position of the lever is important.

Comment: @Stephie Nice find! Yeah, it's absolutely a combination moka pot and steamer. Which is very odd to me because I can't fathom it producing enough steam at sufficient pressure to actually steam milk...

Comment: Specifically this photo confirms my suspicion. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gLrg.jpg

Comment: @Stephie, yes, I had seen the other post on this device. I suppose I was wondering if the other poster had had any luck or some intel to share. The last time I looked this up on the internet, I found some instructions. But my foolproof method of retaining the information has failed. Duh.

Comment: @steveluscher, have you figured this contraption out yet?